# Multi-line, multi-data source auto complete textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a jquery plugin that supports multi-line ,multi-data source autocomplete textarea?
By that I mean every line in the textarea is bound to a different data source which is specific only for that line. For example, on the first line of textarea the user types in a country name,he is then presented with a list of countries, makes his choice and then presses Enter key. He is now on the second line of the textarea and this time he will type in the city name, another list comes up and he goes through the same process until he completes the form.

This is my attempt to simplify data input in the application Im building because it has lots of dropdown and input boxes.

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. People *know* how to fill out forms, they don't know how your custom `textarea` thing will work.

Comment: I agree, why not split the fields up into an easy to understand form? Unless this is some sort of template for like a resume - but still - why not use a form?

Comment: The form is already split up and the fields that related to each other are grouped. But most of this fields are dropdown boxes. I just want to minimize switching from mouse to keyboard as they type in the values.

Comment: This is a lot like intellisense, where the dropdown is syntax aware. In your case the syntax is just the position within the form. I have used the asuggest plugin. I think you can probably modify the suggested list base on some context within the textarea.

Comment: Try using autocomplete textboxes. Joining all input in one textarea will confuse most webusers. Also a single textarea can get whiped it they happen to touch esc, and if there are multiple lines that will annoy them.

Comment: I agree with David. the autocomplete plugin works quite well.